# How to put multiple tables in the DataTable jQuery plugin

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

I've been using this [PLUGIN](http://www.datatables.net) for representing my data from mysql database.

I am using this script [EXAMPLE](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) for server side processing.

Now this script is working perfectly why you have one table. But problem is occurring when I have multitable query.

For example I have:

```
$sWhere = "a.ID=b.ID AND b.Name=c.Name";
```

This is only where variable. If you go to the link that I gave you can see the php script that is used to fetch data. When I put more then one table I get unique table error. And the search functions can't work.

Can someone show me how to use this script to be able to have multiple tables included in one query.

If you need more source let me know.

EDIT:

My HTML:

```
<table id="table_my" width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" class="chart_1">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="even">
                        <th>A</th>
                        <th>B</th>
                        <th>C</th>
                        <th>D</th>
                        <th>E</th>
                        <th>F</th>
                        <th>G</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

              <tbody>
              </tbody>
              </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a change in the HTML Markup, when that multitable query executes. Why don't you compare both and check for the difference in the HTML Markup?

The markup for DataTable jQuery plugin should be this way:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column Name</th>
            <th>Column Name</th>
            <th>Column Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row Value</td>
            <td>Row Value</td>
            <td>Row Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row Value</td>
            <td>Row Value</td>
            <td>Row Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row Value</td>
            <td>Row Value</td>
            <td>Row Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row Value</td>
            <td>Row Value</td>
            <td>Row Value</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also remember, it doesn't work with more than one `tbody` or `thead` tag and tables without these tags. Also, if you have used `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes, it doesn't work.

Comment: My table print I mean columns and data is correct when I use one table in query. Problem is when my query fetches data from multiple tables. My problem is probably with php

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the rendered HTML for both single table query and multi table query?

Comment: Maybe I am not explaining as I should I want to represent only one table in html. But my query is fetching data from more then one tables. As you can see in the above question. HTML stay only one table

Comment: I understand that. But when you fetch from multiple tables, you had issue right, so lets compare that markup of the single HTML table of multiple DB tables so that it doesn't deviate from the required thing. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Okay, I am getting a JSON format problem. Something like table needs to be unique

Comment: Once I see both the markups, I will be able to help you for sure... :)

Comment: I don't have anything else then this :) tell me what I need to show you

Comment: Show the generated source of HTML from the PHP, where you can see the `<table>` tags. I need the markup of both the tables.

Answer (score 0):

from ***www.facebook.com/Heanock Z behere Ethiopia*** 
*

### Answer for the above problem

*
i just use like i am using in php or other language and i have two tables to be joined 
**tbl_employees**
**

emp_id

** int(11) auto_increment primary key,
**emp_name** varchar(50),
**sex** enum('female','male'),
**emp_dept** varchar(50),
**emp_salary** double,
**job** int(11)  = is foreign key that i will share from the second table

**tbl_job**

**

job_id

** int(11) primary key,
**job_name** varchar(50),
**job_cat** varchar950)

lastly here is my code in ***php mysql plus datatable***

Emp ID
        Emp Name
        Sex
        Department
        Salary
        Job
        Edit
        Delete

```
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT emp_id,emp_name,sex,emp_dept,emp_salary,job_name FROM tbl_employees,tbl_job where job=job_id ORDER BY emp_id DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['emp_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['emp_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['sex']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['emp_dept']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['emp_salary']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['job_name']; ?></td>
```

if you have any question related with above problem write me @ heanocklove@gmail.com or My facebook Page listed Above

Thanks very much